# В консоли не выводятся русские буквы

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, кодировка

В powershell не выводятся русские буквы. В теге  находится русский текст, я пытаюсь его вывести, но в терминале показываются непонятные символы.
[image: screenshot1]

[image: 1]

Comment: у вас явно указана кодировака utf-8 и язык английский!

Comment: Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код и/или ошибки в виде скриншотов. Неудобно читать, невозможно копировать. Добавьте текстом в вопрос (кнопка [edit])

Answer (score 6, accepted):

У вас файл открывается с системной кодировкой, а под windows это будет не `utf-8`, а `cp1251`

Явно укажите в `open` кодировку файла, т.е. `utf-8`:

```
with open("blank/index.html", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    src = f.read()
```

---

А вообще, лучше открывайте файл в режиме бинарного чтения, тогда кодировку не нужно указывать, а `BeautifulSoup` сможет сам разобраться:

```
with open("blank/index.html", "rb") as f:
    src = f.read()
```

Кст, вместо `lxml` можно использовать встроенный парсер `html.parser`

Comment: Спасибо, помогло

Comment: @Dimasikk, пожалуйста, и не забудьте [проголосовать и принять ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Answer (score -1):

```
title2= title.text    
print(repr(title2))
```

или можете сразу декодировать.

```
title.encoding = 'utf-8'
print(title.text)
```

Comment: Ничего не изменилось